# expanding a mysql JOIN query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need to alter my existing JOIN query below to also include the data from `users.image` correlating to the `UserID` of the post maker. Something like:

`users.image WHERE users.UserID = posts.userid`

I am not very good with join queries yet. How would I do this?

Existing Query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT  posts.* FROM  listen JOIN posts ON posts.userid = listen.listenid WHERE listen.userid = '$user_id' ORDER BY DATE desc") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: SELECT  posts.*, users.image FROM  listen JOIN posts ON (posts.userid = listen.listenid) JOIN users ON (users.UserID = posts.userid) WHERE listen.userid = '$user_id' ORDER BY DATE desc")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another JOIN clause:

```
SELECT  posts.* 
FROM  listen 
JOIN posts ON (posts.userid = listen.listenid) 
JOIN users ON (users.UserID = posts.userid)
WHERE listen.userid = '$user_id' 
ORDER BY DATE desc
```

You may need to change the JOIN to a specific join such as LEFT JOIN, depending on what you're after.

Btw, it is easier to see the query on multiple lines.

Edit:  You'll probably want to add additional items that you are selecting with your fields, such as `SELECT posts.*, users.*`

Comment: That makes sense an doesn't error but doesn't return the value I am trying to get.

Comment: The query selects all the appropriate items but not the row of images I am trying to add... Is there something I need to do to select the matching users.image row and add it to the results?

Comment: Currently it only selects posts.* but no field from `listen` or `users`. SELECT user.image, posts.* FROM ...